java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.codehaus.stax2.ri.EmptyIterator.getInstance()Lorg/codehaus/stax2/ri/EmptyIterator in Weblogic14.1.1
Any idea how to get past the above error?
my pom shows I am using com.sun.xml.ws:jaxws-rt 2.2.8  which I believe has dependencies on org.codehaus.woodstox:stax2-api 3.1.1  which I believe is what is throwing this error
